# add background color from logo to menu using css

Tags: html, css, magento, menu

please go through below link :

http://2.kidsdial.com/customer/account/login

and login with this email id : kidsdial2@gmail.com & password : kidsdial2

than please check this : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

on top , you can see : Listings, Orders, Returns . above there is a

logo image: totaltoys.

I want to display background color from top of the logo [totaltoys] to bottom of the menu as like this : [image]

Comment: Please don't share website login details in here, and explain the question correctly - I assume that can be done in javascript.

Comment: actually this is demo site. can you please help me for this...

Comment: please check the updated question and let me know if you need any clarifications. but please help for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can test these CSS rules

```
#horizontalmenu .mymenu > li {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    width: 100px;
}
#main_header .header-container .header {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
#horizontalmenu{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: please check this now : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/ almost done, please help me for background color for logo also.....

Comment: this is a picture I cannot help you to change a picture here

Comment: this picture has a backround color, he has not a transparent backround, so even if you change the CSS background-color, the backround-color of the image stay as the backround of the image

Comment: okay, means is i have to do photoshop for adding background color for this image ?

Comment: please help me for this : on above table , you can see " Delete Products" , it should display in above table at the end. please help me for this. i need 90 minutes to post one more question.....

Comment: can't understand what do you mean when you say ``in above table at the end`, you mean `on top of the table but at right` or `on bottom of the table`?

Comment: actually in this link : 2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist you can see a table below the menu. there you can see " Delete Products" , i wanted to display "Delete products" in last column of table . please help me for this

Comment: "Delete Products" button should display next to "submit" button

Answer (score 0):

I would remove .bkg_header_bottom from:

```
.adapt-0 .em-box-custom .bkg_header_bottom, .em-box-custom .container_header, .bkg_header_bottom{
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

and possibly remove the color here as well so you aren't duplicating code:

```
.adapt-0 .em-box-custom .bkg_header_bottom, .em-box-custom .container_header, .bkg_header_bottom {
    background-color: #3fbdf7;
    background-image: url(../images/stripes/blank.gif);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
}
```

Add the background color you want here, this class contain both elements you want colored:

```
.page.one-column{
    background-color: #3fbdf7;
}
```

Comment: do you want me to remove first 2 codes..... can you please give internal css for  this instead of removing from external css....

Comment: +1 vote from me . please help me for this : on below you can see  table , you can see " Delete Products" , it should display in above table at the end. please help me for this. i need 90 minutes to post one more question.....

Comment: actually in this link : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/ you can see a table below the menu. there you can see " Delete Products" , i wanted to display "Delete products" in last column of table . please help me for this.

Comment: "Delete Products" button should display next to "submit" button